How can I make a new directory
In the tutorial:Recording and playing back data is writen the order:Let’s also make a new directory to store our saved recordings, just as good practice.
How do I create this directory?

are you asking how to create a directory in Windows or some other OS?

Use GUI or mkdir ?
